# Carregar HTML em DIV recebido via requisição AJAX convertendo carácteres especiais

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estou dando manutenção numa aplicação onde existe agora a necessidade de carregar numa div um HTML vindo do banco de dados. Com relação ao retorno desse HTML do banco d dados, está tranquilo, já recebo os valores num JSON e poderia (eventualmente) carregá-lo na view, mas simplesmente não carrega.

Vou mostrar o código:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '<minha url>',
    dataType: 'html',
    type: 'post', 
    data: {<meus parametros>},
    success: function(data){
        $('#load-html-template').html(data[0].TemplateText);
    }
```

Quanto ao `dataType`, já mandei como HTML (não retorna nada), JSON (retorna o HTML como uma string), XML (não carrega nada), etc...

***Resolvido uma parte do problema - entrando em outro***

Obrigado pela ajuda galera até aqui, mas agora tive acesso direto ao banco de dados e percebi que, o código HTML está em formato de carácteres especiais, desta forma:

```
&lt;html&gt;
&lt;head&gt;

&lt;/head&gt;

&lt;body&gt;
    &lt;table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%"&gt;
        &lt;tr&gt;
            &lt;td width="2%"&gt;&amp;#160;&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;td width="920px"&gt;
                 &lt;div style="line-height:120%;font-family:Arial;font-size:15pt;background-color:#e8eae8;"&gt;&lt;form action=""&gt;&lt;table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" width="99%"&gt;

......
```

Pois bem, como converter essas tags para as tags HTML em questão? Já fiz isso, mas mesmo assim o problema segue...

```
mystring.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/"/g, "&quot;");
```

Poderiam me dar uma força!!!
Desde já agradeço!!!

Comment: Podes colocar aqui o que aparece com `console.log(data);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tentei o seguinte:

```
var html = String(data[0].TemplateText).replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
        .replace(/&quot;/g, '"')
        .replace(/&#39;/g, "'")
        .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
        .replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
```

Comment: Funcionou... Thanks!!!

Comment: Não há necessidade de utilizar aspas duplas para atribuir aspas simples numa string. Basta atribuir com escape: `'\''`.